# Rails 3: How to create a named scope based on Controller's method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, named-scope

In my `ApplicationController` I have the `demo_mode?` method (which returns `true` when the currently logged in user type is "demo").

`Post` model has the `publisher_id` field, which refers to `Users` table.

`User` has the `user_type` field, one of the possible values of which is "demo".

Bottom line: post `p` was published by a "demo" user if and only if:

```
User.find(p.publisher_id).user_type == "demo"
```

I would like to create a named scope `Post.relevant` that will return:

- all posts that were published by "demo" users, if `demo_mode? == true`
- all posts that were published by non "demo" users, if `demo_mode? == false`

How would you create such a named scope ? Should I move `demo_mode?` to other place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lambda to make a dynamic scope, and keep the session info out of the model:

In your model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :relevant, lambda {|demo_mode|
     joins(:publisher).
     where("publishers.user_type #{demo_mode ? '' : 'NOT'} LIKE 'demo'")
  }
end
```

And then in the controller:

```
posts = Post.relevant(demo_mode?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    scope :relevant, joins("INNER JOIN users ON (users.user_type = 'demo')").where("publisher_id = users.id")

end
```

Comment: I don't see how this takes into consideration the `demo_mode?` method ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the demo state is determined by the session so only the controller knows about it. On the other hand, the controller (or possibly the view) is the only place where you would want to query the scope. If all of this is correct, I would add a method to ApplicationController like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def relevant_posts
    Post.joins(:publisher).
      where("publishers.user_type #{demo_mode? ? '' : 'NOT'} LIKE 'demo'")
  end

  ...
  helper_method :relevant_posts # if you want it to be available in views
end
```

Technically, this is not a named scope. Rails 3, however does not make much of a difference between named scopes and the standard query interface.