# Rails 3: Is that possible to expose Controller's method to model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`helper_method` exposes Controller's method to a view.

Is that possible to expose Controller's method to a model ?

Comment: Could you explain why you need this?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC model is trying to separate code. So if you wanna access code in controllers from model. This means design wise, you may be wrong somewhere. If you wanna share code between controllers and models, it is suggested to put it in to library.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but in most cases this is a very, very bad idea.

You may want to define the method *in the model*, and call it in the controller's action.

Without knowing what you want to achieve, it's hard to give you more detailed instructions.